# Конструктор с++

Tags: c++, конструктор, класс

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int a;
public:
    A(int a):a(a){}
    int get() { return a; }
};
class B :public A {
    int b;
public:
    ******
    int get() { return b; }
};

void F() {
    A* a = new B();
}
```

Нашел такую задачу. Вместо * , я так понял , нужно вставить конструктор ? Пробовал варианты , но ошибка что для класса А конструктора по умолчанию нет. Нужна помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или добавьте, скажем, `=1` в конструктор `A`:

```
A(int a = 0):a(a){}
```

Как я понимаю, наличие поля `b` требует от вас передачи в конструктор параметра, так что

```
B(int b = 1):A(),b(b){}
```

или

```
B(int b = 1, int a = 0):A(a),b(b){}
```

Comment: это же надо уметь написать три варианта и все неверные:)

Comment: Рад, что порадовал вас. Верные, но не для данного `F`. Так вас устроит? Кстати, первый вариант вполне работоспособен: https://ideone.com/h5jOWw

Comment: Не, сам код то правильный, но в задании просят только дописать код конструктора класса B вместо звездочек. Хотя третий вариант можно все таки считать более-менее правильным (правда он уже после моего комментария был)

Comment: Не всегда в программировании надо менять там, где просят... Как в медицине - не всегда надо лечить там, где болит :(

Comment: понятно. Что же сделаешь, но это даже лучше. Чем больше будет такого, тем больше у меня будет высокооплачиваемой работы:)

Comment: @KoVadim А у меня - творческой, где нужен головной мозг, а не спинной :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот где то так

```
B() : A(1) {}
```

или вместо 1 подставьте нужное число